# Alternative Asp.net designer/IDE?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Are there alternatives to Visual Studio 2008/Visual Web Developer Express for developing ASP.Net applications?

Answer (score 4):

There are two that I know of:

[#Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) for Windows, which doesn't appear to support ASP.Net very well

and

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Main_Page) for Linux, Windows and soon Mac OS. Based on #Develop, with modifications for Mono/Gtk# and has better support for ASP.Net as of 2.0, [which is currently in beta](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Feb-19-1.html).

In addition to being free, they are also a good way to get support for lesser-known CLR/DLR languages like Boo, IronPython and IronRuby.

Comment: But the ASP.Net support of #develop is weak yet... :(

Comment: Yes, I was making an edit to that effect. MonoDevelop looks to be a better alternative.

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/overview.aspx?key=web) also has a limited support for ASP.NET. It will allow you to drop in the web controls and the like, but you'll have to write up your own code behind and compile from the back end unless you go with a Web Site deployment as opposed to a Web Application Project deployment.

EDIT: Well, looking at the features in Expression Web 2 (I'm still using 1.0), they seem to have a built in ASP.NET development server (as well as PHP I might add) to test things out with, so it will take you one step closer.

Answer (score 1):

for the GUI you can also use Macromedia DreamWeaver,

Comment: The thought of this makes me a sad panda.

Comment: i never used for asp.net but it is an alternative

Answer (score 1):

[Delphi Prism](http://www.codegear.com/products/delphi/prism) - 
Delphi development solution for .NET and Mono.

Answer (score 1):

**Foo Basic Web Studio IDE for Asp.net** is packed with great features and writes JS and jQuery for you, it is so easy to code with.

For instance you can create a modal nested popup with just one line of code and to reference a control that is located on another form is easy with their global control referencing, just code me.controlid.property no matter which form the control is on.

Its the only IDE that has a built in obfuscator and ability to lock your script. 
Go to their site [www.**foobasic**.com](http://foobasic.com) for all the other great features this alternative ASP.NET Ajax IDE offers.