# ASP.NET Page Designer for Linux

Tags: .net, asp.net, linux, mono, monodevelop

Is there a simple, yet decent .aspx designer that runs on Linux? I've since all the ones in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588261/alternative-asp-net-designer-ide) question but none satisfied the "runs on Linux" condition. By decent, I mean that the designer allow me drop asp.net webcontrols on a webpages for futher use in Monodevelop.

Answer (score 1):

[X-Develop](http://www.omnicore.com/en/xdevelop.htm) doesn't have it yet.  I know there was some work on using MozEmbed for this functionality for MonoDev (IIRC on a SOC a few years back), but never got integrated.

If you *REALLY* need this functionality, then a copy of Windows (in a VM), and MS Expression Web or Web Developer 2008 Express are probably the best option.  It's either that, or learn to writ markup, which is generally the way many developers do things.